# changing the MFMailComposeViewController navigationBar title font

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a `MFMailComposeViewController` and when I've set the subject it also sets it as the subject.
The question is how do I customize the font of the title and color?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[picker setSubject:@"Feedback for MyApp"];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i've changed the font generally for my apps from the app-delegate for all navigation bars of all view controllers.  if you don't mind it changing all of your navigation bar title fonts, put something like the following in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`

```
    if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
        // set the navigation bar font to "courier-new bold 14"
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor lightGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"CourierNewPS-BoldMT" size:14.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
                                                    nil]];
```

*update:*
if you want it specific to this one case, you can probably use appearanceWhenContainedIn: using the arguments Alexander Akers suggested in the comment below, since UIViewController inherits from UIAppearanceContainer.  i know appearanceWhenContainedIn: works in other cases such as UIBarButtonItems contained in UINavigationBar, so it should work similarly for this situation.

Comment: `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn: [MFMailComposeViewController class], nil]` ?

Comment: That code would only change the navigation bar's appearance when it's contained inside the mail compose view controller.

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers, updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.  i have experience using appearanceWhenContainedIn: for UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar; i haven't used it for this type of case, but it should indeed work.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is it can't be done because of cross-process restrictions.  I can change the color, size, and font (if it's a built-in system font), but attempts to change it to any of the fonts included in my app fail.

Answer (score -1):

Since the `MFMailComposeViewController` is an instance of a `UINavigationController`, you can set the titleView of its `topViewController` as follows:

```
UIViewController *controller = [mailController topViewController];

UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 170.0f, 44.0f)];
titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleView.bounds];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = @"Custom Font";
label.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:27.0f];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

[titleView addSubview:label];
[label release];

controller.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
[titleView release];
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work, I copy pasted your code and replaced mailController with mine

Comment: @xonegirlz, you mentioned, you tried this code.  i remember having problems with this style of changing the control bar characteristics, which is why i've come to rely on the UIAppearance stuff as described in my answer above.  did you try that as well?  any updates?