# UINavigationBar of MFMailComposeViewController Not Consistently Showing the Right Image/Color

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working with my app that calls up the `MFMailComposeViewController` from a particular `UITableView` when a `navigationBarButton` has been tapped.

Because I have themes in my app (a choice of 12), I first thought it would be good to have the `MFMailComposeViewController` come up with the same theme and I'm creating this directly from code and not from the Storyboard.

While testing my app, I'm noticing that the `NavigationBar` image does not remain consistent each and every time this view is launched. Within Storyboard, I have two navigation bar items on the right side which is implemented by having a UIView with a UIToolbar embedded in that view and finally the two navigation bar button items in that UIToolbar. This allows me to have both next to each other.

With this in mind, I've noticed a pattern. If I click on the Email icon, the MFMailComposeViewController that comes up has a NavigationBar that takes the appropriate image. If I tap the second icon in the navigation bar (Plus icon) and then go and tap the Email icon again, the UINavigationBar is white and therefore it doesn't load the image. I've put in NSLogs and the code is getting called appropriately for setting the UINavigationBar, but this is the pattern; click on the other UINavigationBar Button item first and then click on the Email and the UINavigationBar does not show the UIImage. 
Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)savePDFAndEmail:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"An email"];

        NSString *emailBody = @"Hello";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        mailer.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
        [[mailer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        }];
    }
}
```

**Problem**

So, to reiterate the issue: when I select and call up this `MFMailComposeViewController` in the app by tapping the navigation bar button, the UIImage is shown if I click on the Email button first, but if I click on the Plus button and then the email, the uinavigationbar image is not shown on the MFMailComposeViewController.

What I want here is for the `UINavigationBar` to always take the selected theme's `UINavigationBar` image.

The AppDelegate already sets the code for the selected theme and the `UINavigationBar's` image, but it seems to not get applied here. Here's a little snippet:

```
else if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Simplicity"])
{
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenishNav.png"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

What can I do to ensure the `MFMailComposeViewController's` `UINavigationBar` image remains that of the selected theme?

Every other view is perfectly fine; it's just this one.

The weird thing is the fact that elsewhere in my app, I call another `MFMailComposeViewController` from a `UITableViewCell` with the exact same code (just changing the subject, etc) and that keeps the Image of the `UINavigationBar` every time; it's just from here with the `UINavigationBar` Button that the image does not remain.

Update: I've found some steps to reproduce this. In the view where I have the UINavigationBar button that calls the MFMailComposerViewController, I also have a second NavigationBar item that allows a user to add an entry from here. That is created in Storyboard with a UIView and a UIToolbar embedded within that view and the two NavigationBar items (Email and Add) inside that toolbar. If I click on the mail icon, it appears consistently with the image. However, if I tap the plus button in the nav bar, cancel that and then click on the email icon, it doesn't display the UINavigationBar image when the MFMailComposer comes up.

Any guidance would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really lengthy, however answer are pretty simple.

Please refer these Stack Over flow post that talks about changing the `MFMailComposeViewController` 's navigationBar & tints. You can try it in your case. however your question is not a duplicate, So I am referring the related posts here.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768736/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-appearance-settintcolor-getting-lost-ios-7)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173693/changing-the-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-navigationbar-title-font)

**UPDATED SECTION**

- The idea is to control the `UINavigationBar` appearance in `viewWillAppear` method of any viewController.
- Here is the [Video](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/mfMailComposer/MFMailComposer.mov) of this.
- Here is the screen shots.
  [image]
- Finally if you want the sample [code](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/mfMailComposer/mailComposer.zip), you can check it. There is no use of Singleton. You can modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Balram. I have seen those posts before and unfortunately, I'm in the same position. The UINavigationBar does not consistently take the image of the selected theme. So if I open up the MFMailComposer once, it may take the theme, but if I close it and open it again, it may be all white again without taking the theme. The only thing I can think to make this consistent is to create a new ViewController in Storyboard with a custom class for the MFMail and then apply my theming code in the viewWillAppear, but that seems like a lot of extra work

Comment: I'm looking at this as a bug, because elsewhere in my app, I have another MFMailComposeViewController (that's called from a UITableViewCell rather than a UINavigationBarButton and it always keeps the same image. I'm not really sure what I need to do to get this UINavigationBar button to work with the theme. Unless I, when creating the MFMailComposeViewController call my "theming" method

Comment: Update: calling the "theme" changing method does not work either.

Comment: Updated my question with a scenario that I've found

Comment: Do you have any further ideas Balram?

Comment: Yes I have. But I am making sure it works well rather than to post any immature code. May be tomorrow. If this discussion needs more comments, please switch over to email to respect this forum & avoid stack overflow warnings..!!!

Comment: Just to give you an idea, please have a shared instance of MFMailComposer & initialize it where you set the theme. Later Use the same instance but change the subject or To values as per your need, so that you get a consistent behavior in terms of UIAppearance.

Comment: Thanks Balram - that does kind of make sense - I'll see what I can do with that and perhaps we can set up a chat session tomorrow

Comment: @Lavanya : You can check the UPDATED SECTION here in answer.

Comment: Many thanks Balram for taking the time out to do that. It looks great and unfortunately I couldn't get it working. The reason is because the difference I think is that my "button" that calls the MFMailCompose is in a toolBar inside a UIView in the NavigationBar. I've copied your code all in and traced it and it goes to "set" the NavigationBar image for the MFMailCompose, but it never actually does it. I think this is an iOS Bug now that I've plugged your code in. With this thinking, rather than spend too much more time.. can I ask you how I would permanently set the MFMailCompose ...

Comment: navigationBar to be the colour black (regardless of which theme is being used?)

Comment: So rather than get a theme, I just want to permanently set the MFMailComposeViewController to have a black Navigation Bar colour

Comment: Add a New file & subclass it from `MFMailComposeViewController`.
in `viewWillAppear` method of this new file, do whatever colour stuff you want.  Like this. 

`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}`

That will solve your issue.
Conversation is getting long. Please chat @ tiwari.balram@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks @Balram - that did it and that's really helpful. Thanks again so much for your effort with this. Really appreciate this and really appreciate you writing out the sample program as well.

Comment: Thanks. The other thing which I see that you have diverted from your original approach. I am wondering why the solution did not fit to the original approach. Can you provide information about your Views, SubViews & may be your design towards this line `my "button" that calls the MFMailCompose is in a toolBar inside a UIView in the NavigationBar.`

Comment: navigationbar inside project also changes background on mail display

Comment: Note that this approach does not seem to work on my iPhone 6+ running 8.3, as well as the latest simulator for the same device. The simulator shows the problem more clearly. It starts by showing the themed navigation bar, but switches to white once the content of the message loads.

Answer (score 0):

//Try

```
-(void)displayMailComposerSheet
{
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }


    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        picker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",Data_Dict);

    [picker setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"short_name"]]];

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    //  // Attach an image to the email
    //  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"jpg"];
    //  NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    //  [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = str_sms;
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Dismiss Mail/SMS view controller
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    ////NSLog(@"%u",result);


    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // Uncomment to change the color of back button
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // Uncomment to assign a custom backgroung image
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg_ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        // Uncomment to change the back indicator image

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

        // Uncomment to change the font style of the title

        NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

        CGFloat verticalOffset = -4;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }


    if(result == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail sending canceled" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else if(result == 1)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Result: Mail saved" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else if(result == 2)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail sent" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else if(result == 3)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail sending failed" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail not sent" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh - great answer, but unfortunately that did not work. Thanks so much for the answer though. I've just updated my question with the found scenario that causes this but I'm not sure what to do to fix it!